# How to fix syntax error in this beginner Python AI code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence

Making beginner Ai to distingush apple from orange from weight and texture and it comes with a syntax error on labels
Here's the code:

```
from sklearn import tree

## In Features 1 = Smooth, 0 = Bumpy

features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]
labels = ["apple", "apple", "orange", "orange"]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print clf.predict([[150, 0]])
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Which line is the error on? Which lines can you delete and still get the error? Reduce the code to a minimum that you still don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Your nested list for `features` is missing the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `]`

```
from sklearn import tree

    ## In Features 1 = Smooth, 0 = Bumpy

    features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]] # missed an ] here
    labels = ["apple", "apple", "orange", "orange"]
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
    print clf.predict([[150, 0]])
```

Comment: This is reason to close due to a typo; the problem doesn't qualify for a normal answer.

Answer (score 0):

What was the error you got when running the Python script?

For example:

`>>> x = [ ["x", y"]`

Gives me:

`SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

And even points to the line it failed on. Did you try Googling this? I feel like you're trying to learn something about AI but in a language you're still new to here.